# React - using functions from another file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have two JS files (`functions.js` and `app.js`)
functions.js - contains a big amount of functions ( so putting them together with app.js - isn't best option ). The regular and arrow functions can be passed with `import * as funcs from './functions'` or `import {func1, func2, func3, ...} from './functions'`,
but when I get to the functions with .prototype ( `Array.prototype`/ `HTMLElement.prototype` ) I don't know how to execute them.

Example for a function:

```js
HTMLElement.prototype.findRect = () => {
  console.log("CODE HERE...")
}
```

Someone has an idea how to pass those functions?

Comment: The code snippet assigns a property to `HTMLElement.prototype`. This line will be executed when the file is loaded. That function is not being exported from the module. It looks like this function is supposed to be called as a method on a DOM element. In that context, "importing" such a function and "executing" it doesn't make much sense. Please provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

These are almost like a global function, it needs to be executed once, but after that, you don't have to keep calling it.

Say a file 'abc.js',

```
  ABC.prototype.go = () => {}
```

In another file `app.js`

```
  import 'abc.js'

  const a = new ABC()
  a.go()
```

These prototype is the methods that you can dynamically add to the class `ABC`. Here `ABC` is a class such as  `HTMLElement`, `Array` and etc. You can't invoke them directly, instead you can invoke any instance after you create one out of this class.